# Histogram image maching using opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I need to perform a matching between an image and an histogram I receive as a text.
I do the cdf for both of them:

```
    //Calculating cumulative histogram of src
double total = src.rows*src.cols;
double probSrc[255];
int newValuesSrc[255];
double cuml = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
{
    probSrc[j] = imageHistogram[j]/total; // Probability of each value in image
    cuml = cuml + probSrc[j]; // Cumulative probability of current and all previous values
    double cdfmax = cuml * 255;   // Cumulative probability * max value
    newValuesSrc[j] = (int) round(cdfmax);
    cout << imageHistogram[j] << " "<< probSrc[j] << " " << newValuesSrc[j] << endl;
}
readHistogramFromFile();
//Calculating cumulative histogram from file
double probDst[255];
int newValuesDst[255];
cuml = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
{
    probDst[j] = receivedHistogram[j]/total; // Probability of each value in image
    cuml = cuml + probDst[j]; // Cumulative probability of current and all previous values
    double cdfmax = cuml * 255;   // Cumulative probability * max value
    newValuesDst[j] = (int) round(cdfmax);
    cout << receivedHistogram[j] << " "<< probDst[j] << " " << newValuesDst[j] << endl;
}
```

and I get this values:
For the src image:

```
207677 0.0901376 23
37615 0.016326 27
19098 0.00828906 29
11955 0.0051888 31
8744 0.00379514 32
7386 0.00320573 32
6546 0.00284115 33
6178 0.00268142 34
5967 0.00258984 34
5437 0.00235981 35
5280 0.00229167 36
5127 0.00222526 36
5002 0.00217101 37
4839 0.00210026 37
4754 0.00206337 38
4676 0.00202951 38
4547 0.00197352 39
4517 0.0019605 39
4484 0.00194618 40
4290 0.00186198 40
4197 0.00182161 41
4188 0.00181771 41
4265 0.00185113 42
4229 0.0018355 42
4233 0.00183724 43
4245 0.00184245 43
4358 0.00189149 44
4330 0.00187934 44
4400 0.00190972 45
4474 0.00194184 45
4519 0.00196137 46
4415 0.00191623 46
4477 0.00194314 47
4468 0.00193924 47
4580 0.00198785 48
4416 0.00191667 48
4558 0.0019783 49
4674 0.00202865 49
4705 0.0020421 50
4998 0.00216927 50
4848 0.00210417 51
4782 0.00207552 51
4883 0.00211936 52
4989 0.00216536 52
4957 0.00215148 53
4987 0.0021645 53
5133 0.00222786 54
4967 0.00215582 54
5217 0.00226432 55
5185 0.00225043 56
5140 0.0022309 56
5236 0.00227257 57
5291 0.00229644 57
5458 0.00236892 58
5473 0.00237543 59
5464 0.00237153 59
5495 0.00238498 60
5439 0.00236068 60
5458 0.00236892 61
5557 0.00241189 62
5881 0.00255252 62
5900 0.00256076 63
5935 0.00257595 64
5902 0.00256163 64
6040 0.00262153 65
6203 0.00269227 66
6146 0.00266753 66
6140 0.00266493 67
6075 0.00263672 68
6054 0.0026276 68
6238 0.00270747 69
6060 0.00263021 70
6153 0.00267057 70
6303 0.00273568 71
6231 0.00270443 72
6278 0.00272483 72
6360 0.00276042 73
6359 0.00275998 74
6368 0.00276389 75
6438 0.00279427 75
6329 0.00274696 76
6408 0.00278125 77
6360 0.00276042 77
6378 0.00276823 78
6329 0.00274696 79
6394 0.00277517 79
6517 0.00282856 80
6521 0.0028303 81
6707 0.00291102 82
6788 0.00294618 82
6761 0.00293446 83
6878 0.00298524 84
7004 0.00303993 85
6963 0.00302214 85
7050 0.0030599 86
6940 0.00301215 87
6875 0.00298394 88
7073 0.00306988 89
7035 0.00305339 89
7146 0.00310156 90
7007 0.00304123 91
7159 0.0031072 92
7089 0.00307682 92
7185 0.00311849 93
7410 0.00321615 94
7237 0.00314106 95
7334 0.00318316 96
7364 0.00319618 97
7452 0.00323437 97
7760 0.00336806 98
7839 0.00340234 99
7882 0.00342101 100
7885 0.00342231 101
8055 0.00349609 102
7923 0.0034388 103
8165 0.00354384 103
8306 0.00360503 104
8271 0.00358984 105
8275 0.00359158 106
8634 0.0037474 107
8684 0.0037691 108
8752 0.00379861 109
9080 0.00394097 110
8958 0.00388802 111
9094 0.00394705 112
9279 0.00402734 113
9234 0.00400781 114
9348 0.00405729 115
9440 0.00409722 116
9431 0.00409332 117
9662 0.00419358 118
9842 0.0042717 119
9816 0.00426042 121
9957 0.00432161 122
10353 0.00449349 123
10626 0.00461198 124
10764 0.00467187 125
10832 0.00470139 126
10767 0.00467318 128
11222 0.00487066 129
11469 0.00497786 130
11661 0.0050612 131
11731 0.00509158 133
12023 0.00521832 134
12086 0.00524566 135
12094 0.00524913 137
12362 0.00536545 138
12364 0.00536632 139
12659 0.00549436 141
12587 0.00546311 142
12776 0.00554514 144
13037 0.00565842 145
13252 0.00575174 147
13425 0.00582682 148
13595 0.00590061 150
13795 0.00598741 151
14308 0.00621007 153
14232 0.00617708 154
14657 0.00636155 156
14966 0.00649566 157
14867 0.00645269 159
15051 0.00653255 161
15510 0.00673177 162
15357 0.00666536 164
15326 0.00665191 166
15308 0.0066441 168
15316 0.00664757 169
15321 0.00664974 171
15298 0.00663976 173
15435 0.00669922 174
15496 0.00672569 176
15307 0.00664366 178
15343 0.00665929 179
15356 0.00666493 181
15315 0.00664714 183
15444 0.00670312 185
15346 0.00666059 186
15583 0.00676345 188
15429 0.00669661 190
15641 0.00678863 191
15661 0.00679731 193
15638 0.00678733 195
15689 0.00680946 197
15866 0.00688628 198
15552 0.00675 200
15150 0.00657552 202
15185 0.00659071 203
14941 0.00648481 205
14989 0.00650564 207
14585 0.0063303 208
14718 0.00638802 210
14553 0.00631641 212
14612 0.00634201 213
14520 0.00630208 215
14358 0.00623177 216
13931 0.00604644 218
13580 0.0058941 220
13370 0.00580295 221
13281 0.00576432 222
13053 0.00566536 224
12711 0.00551693 225
12556 0.00544965 227
12556 0.00544965 228
12125 0.00526259 229
12184 0.00528819 231
11975 0.00519748 232
12198 0.00529427 233
11919 0.00517318 235
11898 0.00516406 236
11589 0.00502995 237
11348 0.00492535 239
11011 0.00477908 240
10523 0.00456727 241
10388 0.00450868 242
9795 0.0042513 243
9251 0.00401519 244
9014 0.00391233 245
8436 0.00366146 246
8266 0.00358767 247
7851 0.00340755 248
7299 0.00316797 249
6996 0.00303646 250
6303 0.00273568 250
5625 0.00244141 251
5375 0.0023329 251
5102 0.00221441 252
4747 0.00206033 253
4313 0.00187196 253
3809 0.00165321 253
3307 0.00143533 254
2756 0.00119618 254
2276 0.000987847 254
1935 0.000839844 255
1617 0.000701823 255
1087 0.000471788 255
547 0.000237413 255
217 9.4184e-05 255
31 1.34549e-05 255
4 1.73611e-06 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
```

And for the histogram I receive:

```
10 4.34028e-06 0
11 4.77431e-06 0
12 5.20833e-06 0
13 5.64236e-06 0
14 6.07639e-06 0
15 6.51042e-06 0
16 6.94444e-06 0
17 7.37847e-06 0
18 7.8125e-06 0
19 8.24653e-06 0
20 8.68056e-06 0
22 9.54861e-06 0
24 1.04167e-05 0
26 1.12847e-05 0
28 1.21528e-05 0
30 1.30208e-05 0
34 1.47569e-05 0
38 1.64931e-05 0
42 1.82292e-05 0
50 2.17014e-05 0
60 2.60417e-05 0
70 3.03819e-05 0
80 3.47222e-05 0
90 3.90625e-05 0
100 4.34028e-05 0
120 5.20833e-05 0
140 6.07639e-05 0
160 6.94444e-05 0
160 6.94444e-05 0
150 6.51042e-05 0
140 6.07639e-05 0
130 5.64236e-05 0
120 5.20833e-05 0
110 4.77431e-05 0
100 4.34028e-05 0
90 3.90625e-05 0
80 3.47222e-05 0
70 3.03819e-05 0
60 2.60417e-05 0
50 2.17014e-05 0
40 1.73611e-05 0
30 1.30208e-05 0
20 8.68056e-06 0
10 4.34028e-06 0
10 4.34028e-06 0
10 4.34028e-06 0
10 4.34028e-06 0
11 4.77431e-06 0
12 5.20833e-06 0
13 5.64236e-06 0
14 6.07639e-06 0
15 6.51042e-06 0
16 6.94444e-06 0
17 7.37847e-06 0
18 7.8125e-06 0
19 8.24653e-06 0
20 8.68056e-06 0
22 9.54861e-06 0
24 1.04167e-05 0
26 1.12847e-05 0
28 1.21528e-05 0
30 1.30208e-05 0
34 1.47569e-05 0
38 1.64931e-05 0
42 1.82292e-05 0
50 2.17014e-05 0
60 2.60417e-05 0
70 3.03819e-05 0
80 3.47222e-05 0
90 3.90625e-05 0
100 4.34028e-05 0
120 5.20833e-05 0
140 6.07639e-05 0
160 6.94444e-05 0
160 6.94444e-05 0
150 6.51042e-05 0
140 6.07639e-05 0
130 5.64236e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
110 4.77431e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
11 4.77431e-06 1
12 5.20833e-06 1
13 5.64236e-06 1
14 6.07639e-06 1
15 6.51042e-06 1
16 6.94444e-06 1
17 7.37847e-06 1
18 7.8125e-06 1
19 8.24653e-06 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
22 9.54861e-06 1
24 1.04167e-05 1
26 1.12847e-05 1
28 1.21528e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
34 1.47569e-05 1
38 1.64931e-05 1
42 1.82292e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
150 6.51042e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
130 5.64236e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
110 4.77431e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
11 4.77431e-06 1
12 5.20833e-06 1
13 5.64236e-06 1
14 6.07639e-06 1
15 6.51042e-06 1
16 6.94444e-06 1
17 7.37847e-06 1
18 7.8125e-06 1
19 8.24653e-06 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
22 9.54861e-06 1
24 1.04167e-05 1
26 1.12847e-05 1
28 1.21528e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
34 1.47569e-05 1
38 1.64931e-05 1
42 1.82292e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
150 6.51042e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
130 5.64236e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
110 4.77431e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
160 6.94444e-05 1
150 6.51042e-05 1
140 6.07639e-05 1
130 5.64236e-05 1
120 5.20833e-05 1
110 4.77431e-05 1
100 4.34028e-05 1
90 3.90625e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
10 4.34028e-06 1
20 8.68056e-06 1
30 1.30208e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
40 1.73611e-05 1
50 2.17014e-05 1
55 2.38715e-05 1
60 2.60417e-05 1
65 2.82118e-05 1
70 3.03819e-05 1
75 3.25521e-05 1
80 3.47222e-05 1
85 3.68924e-05 2
90 3.90625e-05 2
95 4.12326e-05 2
90 3.90625e-05 2
80 3.47222e-05 2
70 3.03819e-05 2
60 2.60417e-05 2
50 2.17014e-05 2
40 1.73611e-05 2
30 1.30208e-05 2
20 8.68056e-06 2
10 4.34028e-06 2
10 4.34028e-06 2
10 4.34028e-06 2
20 8.68056e-06 2
30 1.30208e-05 2
40 1.73611e-05 2
40 1.73611e-05 2
50 2.17014e-05 2
55 2.38715e-05 2
60 2.60417e-05 2
65 2.82118e-05 2
70 3.03819e-05 2
75 3.25521e-05 2
80 3.47222e-05 2
85 3.68924e-05 2
90 3.90625e-05 2
95 4.12326e-05 2
100 4.34028e-05 2
105 4.55729e-05 2
110 4.77431e-05 2
115 4.99132e-05 2
120 5.20833e-05 2
```

As you can see, the src histogram are a lot more distributed than the histrogram I receive ([0-255] against [0-2]).
My question is, what do I do now? How do I match them?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you scale [0-2] histogram to [0-255]? `oldValue * 255 / 2`.

Comment: In fact, your problem seem that both images hasn't the same size as if you add first columns, you don't get the same count.

Comment: I don't understand what the point with it: double cdfmax = cuml * 255;   // Cumulative probability * max value
    newValuesSrc[j] = (int) round(cdfmax);

Comment: You should give precision on what you mean with "perform a matching between an image and an histogram". In fact, an image histogram divide color range (38 in your case) and tell how many pixel are in each sub-range. You look like to use B&W image here as you have one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: What I need to do is to receive a BW image and a text containing 256 numbers and match the image histogram to the text histogram

Comment: When you say: "match the image histogram to the text histogram" Do you mean equality, similarity or something else?

Comment: Equality, using the formula presented here: http://cronos.rutgers.edu/~lrr/dsp%20design%20course/lectures_2012_new/pdf_2012/Histogram%20Processing.pdf in page 22

Comment: I didn't manage to open the link but an image histogram has 256 values with sum of pixel of the corresponding color. Sum of an image histogram values = width * height. I'm not sure that in your case sum of your histograms are the same. However, in both cases, you do ‘/total;‘. If you divide by the sum of respective histograms, it could allow you to move forward.

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the problem, I was working with two different sizes!
thanks!